# Database doesn't exist with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I don't know why I am getting this error. Is there something wrong with my database configuration? I am using laravel migration for the database and a vagrant box that came with a slightly different configuration. I figure this must be the reason but I can't figure it out. If anyone could help I would be greatful. Thank you.:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.users' doesn't exist (SQL:      
select * from `users`) (Bindings: array ( ))
```

2013_07_02_170745_create_users_table file:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}

}
```

User.php file:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

database.php

```
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => 'mysql',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => array(

        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),

        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'database',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'root',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        'pgsql' => array(
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'database',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ),

        'sqlsrv' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'database',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),

    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk have not actually be run in the databases.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => array(

        'cluster' => true,

        'default' => array(
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ),

    ),

);
```

routes.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('/users', function()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return View::make('users')->with('users' , $users);
});
```

Comment: Did you run the migration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check to see what your database is named. The error you are getting indicates laravel is looking for a DB named 'database' and the table is (correctly) set at users (database.users).

You'll need to change the 'database' key in the mysql section of /app/config/database.php.

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => '{DATABASE NAME}',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

your database is named database in the config file

`'database'  => 'database',`